# jQuery Slideshow Using CSS class on click

Tags: jquery

I am creating a simple jQuery slideshow using on click. I could go to the next and previous photo of my slider using jQuery's .css. Using the .css in jQuery i could use the "-=400px" for my next button and "-+400px" for my previous button. However the transition is not smooth at all so i would prefer to add a class to have that smooth transition. The problem with that is when i click the button to go to the next image its ok for the first image but when i press it again it wont do anything. Same thing with the previous button. What i would like is add the "-=400px" and the "+-400px" using css addClass. Hopefully someone can help

Thanks.

HTML code:

```
<div class="images">
        <div class="images_inside">
            <img src="imgs/model_01.jpg">
            <img src="imgs/model_02.jpg">
            <img src="imgs/model_04.jpg">
            <img src="imgs/model_05.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
```

CSS code:

```
.images {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images_inside {
    width:1600px;
    height:400px;
}

.images img {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}


.active_next {

    margin-left: -400px; 
    -webkit-transition:all 2s ease; 
    transition:all 2s ease;
}

.active_prev {

    margin-left: 400px;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s ease;
    transition:all 2s ease;
}
```

jQuery Working Code:

```
$(".next").on("click", function(){
    $(".images .images_inside").css("margin-left", "-=400px");
});

$(".prev").on("click", function(){
    $(".images .images_inside").css("margin-left", "+=400px");
});
```

jQuery after adding the class not working code:

```
$(".next").on("click", function(){
    $(".images .images_inside").addClass("active_next");
});

$(".prev").on("click", function(){
    $(".images .images_inside").addClass(".active_prev");
});
```

Comment: Could you share the rest of relevant CSS, and/or setup fiddle?

Comment: I have added the rest relevant CSS nevermind

Comment: You might want to use CSS transforms. It's more performant and smoother than attempting to animate pixel values like margins, paddings, positions and etc.

Comment: There is problem in logic, i would say... class is added on first click, images inside div is moved, and... there is no action on second click (applying of same class doesn't mean anything)... margin should be moved gradually....you need 'steps'....

Comment: How would you guys do it?

Comment: @NoName84, one possible way: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I have tried that also but the transition is not working

Comment: OK got it fixed thanks for ur help!!!